# How do I get a Windows 7 driver into Windows Update?

Tags: windows, windows-7, driver, windows-update

I would like my driver to automatically be detected by Windows 7 when the user connects my device, so all they need to do is connect the device (preferably not requiring administrator privileges).

I have written a USB serial driver for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. This is made up of a CAB and INF file, and is signed. The INF uses Microsoft's usbser.sys so I'm not installing a binary executable. It has my own VID and PID.

To install this at the moment, the user:

1. Downloads my driver and saves locally
2. Connects my device to a USB port
3. Opens device manager, and selects "Update Driver" on my device
4. Browses to my INF and CAB file

I can find information on how to get Windows 10 drivers distributed via Windows Update (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/publish-a-driver-to-windows-update), but nothing about Windows 7.

Does anyone have any guidance or advice on how to do this?

Comment: This question is not suitable for StackOverflow which is about programming issues. Please consider to move it to SuperUser.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on `Super User.`

Comment: Ok. Have posted on Super user. I didn't realise writing software stopped before getting it to the user...